# How to prefill input fields on model error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `resources :campaigns` defined in routes.rb.

If I create a `form_for @campaign` in /campaigns/new.html.erb (campaigns#new), create appropriate fields, and then submit it if there's an error saving the model in `campaigns#create`, if I redirect the browser back to the `campaigns#new`, the form fields appear empty.

I remember there being some trick to it, but I can't seem to Google it because I'm weak on nomenclature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your create action instead of redirecting just render the 'new' page so your @campaign value is set when rendering the form.

Comment: I wrote something like if campaign.save ... else render :action => 'new' and it isn't working. I also set flash to collect the campaign.errors, and they are displaying fine but the campaign doesn't seem to be 'overriding' the previous one. By the previous one I mean the campaign = Campaign.new instance variable I defined to make form_for work. Does that make sense?

Comment: You should use the same @ variable in both actions. Also you could do `if @campaign.valid?` instead of `save`

Comment: Yep it looks about right. @ variables are the same, @ variable.valid? and if not, render :action => 'new'. I type in asdfasfasdf into a field, submit, it returns back to new with a flash of errors but the original fields aren't pre-filled. I must be missing something really simple

Comment: Solution: I needed to restart the server.